# output of quarto html format fails when saved on sharepoint

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I have Quarto html document with the below yaml header and this renders and views just fine when I save on my local directory and open it or view in RStudio.

However, when I save saved output (an html file) on my Corporation's SharePoint site, the tab-set and cold-folding functionality fails (as well as some other polished formatting like the floating table of contents on the right side)

This didn't happen in rmarkdown so I'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong or need specific a format type option if I plan to send this by email.

```
format: 
  html:
    fig-width: 12
    fig-height: 7
    code-overflow: wrap
    toc: true
    embed-resources: true
code-fold: true
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3426) helps.

Comment: I coudn't quite follow it but the code fold / toc works when I send by email, just not when I save on a sharepoint site. Not sure if the linked posts addresses that.